# Why "inline" is incompatible with "virtual"

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual, inline

Can someone explain the below paragraph please, no explanation is given:

> The reason it works is that, in virtually all implementations of C++,
>   virtual functions are implemented with a "virtual function table",
>   which is an array of pointers to functions. **This is incompatible
>   with function inlining because you simply can't have a pointer to
>   inline code**. Thus for most situations, virtual and inline are incompatible; the compiler 
>   will simply ignore the inline statement. **However, there is one situation whereby they are 
>   compatible: where the object is accessed directly instead of through a pointer**.
>
> "High Performance Game Programming in C++", Paul Pedriana

Can someone please explain why the two sentences in bold are so?

Comment: While it is true that function inlining clashes with subtype polymorphism, the author of that paragraph confuses that with the `inline` keyword. The compiler can't really ignore `inline` because it affects semantics (specifically, the one definition rule). And in another sense, it ignores `inline` regardless of `virtual` because it (1) is free to, and does, perform inlining in the absence of `inline` and (2) is free to, and does, not perform inlining in the presence of `inline`.

Comment: @delnan: It's worth noting that only the *keyword* `inline` is not allowed on virtual functions. The function can nonetheless still be `inline` implicitly by virtue of being defined inside the class definition. (E.g. [this is fine](http://pastebin.com/hxJ6ZmNY), but [this is bogus](http://pastebin.com/FjkWFgQ7).)

Comment: @jogojapan added- you can google that title its top link

Comment: @user997112 Why have you deleted the author name? You had added it in the previous edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply means the compiler won't inline a call it has to resolve at run-time.

Suppose you have

```
struct A
{
   virtual void foo() {};
};
```

and

```
void test(A* a)
{ 
   a->foo();
}
```

This call is resolved at runtime. Since `foo()` could have been overriden by a deriving class and `a` could point to an object of a derived type, `a->foo()` can't be inlined - it will be resolved by a lookup.

The second statement means that `virtual` functions *could* be inlined in some situations:

```
void test(A a)
{
   a.foo();
}
```

In this case, `a` is of type `A` (even if the original object passed to the function was a derived type, it was sliced because you passed by value) - the call is guaranteed to call `A::foo` so it can be inlined by the compiler.

Comment: hi and in your very last part, if the parameter was passed by value, you wouldnt be able to inline because the pass-by-reference would require vtable lookup?

Comment: @user997112 if the parameter was passed by reference, yes. But it's passed by value in my example.

Answer (score 4):

First, the keywords aren't incompatible in any way. The paragraph is discussing the underlying implementation. A particular function *call* may be either inlined or go through a virtual dispatch, but usually not both. To understand why, you just need to understand what an inline call or a virtual call is.

An inlined function call is one where at least part of the called function is spliced directly into the calling function. This is a low-level optimization that the compiler may perform even on functions that aren't defined as `inline`. But in the early days when compilers were dumber and executable code size was more important, the keyword was more directly related to the optimization feature.

A virtual call is one where the caller doesn't know exactly what function will be executed. The function's implementation needs to be looked up (dispatched) according to the class at runtime.

So if the function will only be determined at runtime, the compiler cannot splice two functions together. It doesn't know what function would get spliced in.

**But** you can call a `virtual` function without making a special dispatch. This occurs if the compiler can be sure of the object's actual type at compile time. For example, if `dog` is derived from `pet` with a `virtual` method `speak`,

```
dog fido;
fido.speak(); // direct dispatch: we know fido is a dog.
```

But this is not the case if we have a reference:

```
bird buddy;
pet &favorite = prefer_dogs? fido : buddy;
favorite.speak(); // favorite may be a bird or dog: need virtual dispatch
```

Most of the time, when you call a `virtual` function you do so through a virtual dispatch.

---

There is another case, which as far as I know is only theoretical: if the compiler can be sure of the *whole* class hierarchy (or the choices in a given instance), it could add a Boolean test whether `favorite` is a `bird` or a `dog` and inline both function calls as alternatives in an automatically-generated `if … else` statement. But anyway, this is just nuts and bolts that you shouldn't worry about.

What's *important* is that a `virtual` function is called according to the type the object was defined as, and an `inline` function may be defined in a header file. And that's all that matters.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your "and an inline function may be defined in a header file"? I wasn't sure why you said it?

Comment: @user997112 It's the only significant difference between an `inline` function and a non-inline function. Any function you define in a header file must be `inline`, either because you declared it so or implicitly, such as if it is declared inside a `class {}` block or it is a template. And I'll repeat: **That is the only significant meaning of inline.** Don't let anyone tell you it causes the function call to be inlined; that is no longer true in this day and age. The compiler makes a decision independently of the specifier.

Answer (score 0):

It is not "incompatible", just when actually virtual call is placed it is impossible to inline the unknown code. When static call is made to the function inlining will work alright.

The text is not very well formed, but if you already know what it wants to tell, you can find it there. ;-)